# Community Record Details Page Edit Button

Tags: lightning, community

I have some problem on the Record Details Page in Community. When I will click the Edit button as Member it won't do anything. please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check object level permission for that community user's profile, make sure to give Edit permission.
And also check whether that record is shared with this community user - you can find this by clicking on 'Sharing' button on record level as a sys admin.